# Cross fade scenes in ThreeJS upgrade from 101 > 107

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've found [an example](https://github.com/kile/three.js-demos) by Fernando Serrano of how to crossfade between 2 scenes in ThreeJS. [Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/thomasjonas/5L96adke/4/) a slightly modified, working JSFiddle version using ThreeJS 101. Now to my problem...

When upgrading ThreeJS to the latest version (107) there have been some changes to `WebGLRenderer`. The `renderTarget` and `forceClear` argument have been removed from it's `render` function. I've tried to [update my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thomasjonas/5L96adke/3/) and all seems to work fine but my console is showing a lot of errors!

I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be. Is the order or setting the render target and clearing the renderer important? Can I use the same renderer for both render targets?

It would be great if somebody could explain to me what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be. Is the order or setting the render target and clearing the renderer important?

Yes, it is. Think of `WebGLRenderer` as a state machine. You first have to specify whether to use a render target via `.setRenderTarget()` or not. In the next step you can perform an optional clear and the respective rendering.

In line 103, you set `renderer.setRenderTarget(this.fbo)` although `renderer.setRenderTarget(null)` is correct. You can also use the official [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_crossfade) as a code template. I have adopted the fix from there.

> Can I use the same renderer for both render targets?

Yes, no problem.

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3b498ozw/

`three.js R107`

Comment: Thanks so much! Such a waste of time that I didn't use the official example. I must have overlooked it. Make sense to look at it as a state machine. I have to pay attention to set the render target correctly.